# pretty-printing a record using a custom method in Clojure

Tags: clojure, pretty-print, multimethod, pprint

In Clojure 1.5.0, how can I provide a custom pretty-printer for my own record type, defined with defrecord.

```
(defrecord MyRecord [a b])

(defmethod print-method MyRecord [x ^java.io.Writer writer]
  (print-method (:a x) writer))

(defmethod print-dup MyRecord [x ^java.io.Writer writer]
  (print-dup (:a x) writer))

(println (MyRecord. 'a 'b)) ;; a -- OK
(clojure.pprint/pprint (MyRecord. 'a 'b)) ;; {:a a, :b b} -- not OK, I want a
```

I would like `clojure.pprint/pprint` to also use my cutsom printer (which now, should just pretty-prints whatever is in the field `a` of the record for illustration purposes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`clojure.pprint` namespace uses different dispatch mechanisms than the `clojure.core` print functions. You need to use `with-pprint-dispatch` in order to customize `pprint`.

```
(clojure.pprint/with-pprint-dispatch print  ;; Make the dispatch to your print function
  (clojure.pprint/pprint (MyRecord. 'a 'b)))
```

To customize the simple dispatcher, add something like:

```
(. clojure.pprint/simple-dispatch addMethod MyRecord pprint-myrecord)
```

Comment: Just leaving this here because that's why I arrived here: the `pprint-myrecord` function should write to `*out*`, not return a string.

Answer (score 9):

This has been very confusing, with correct answers to different parts of the problem spread around various places, so I put it all together in the hopes that someone might save some time.

I went through all the permutations of defining the multimethods `print-method`, `print-dup`, and `simple-dispatch` for the defrecord, and setting dynamic vars `*print-pprint-dispatch*` and `*print-dup*`.  I put an example defrecord through both `pr` and `pprint` and came up with the following flowchart.  It makes sense now I can see everything at once.

[image]

The permutation code is brute force; I just looked at the outputs and created the Visio diagram directly.  Nothing fancy.

```
(ns print-test
  (:require [clojure.pprint :as pp]))


(defrecord tr000 [val])
(defrecord tr001 [val])
(defrecord tr010 [val])
(defrecord tr011 [val])
(defrecord tr100 [val])
(defrecord tr101 [val])
(defrecord tr110 [val])
(defrecord tr111 [val])


;;(defmethod print-method       tr000 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr000 print-method"))
;;(defmethod print-dup          tr000 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr000 print-dup"))
;;(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr000 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr000 simple-dispatch"))

;;(defmethod print-method       tr001 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr001 print-method"))
;;(defmethod print-dup          tr001 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr001 print-dup"))
(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr001 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr001 simple-dispatch"))

;;(defmethod print-method       tr010 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr010 print-method"))
(defmethod print-dup          tr010 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr010 print-dup"))
;;(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr010 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr010 simple-dispatch"))

;;(defmethod print-method       tr011 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr011 print-method"))
(defmethod print-dup          tr011 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr011 print-dup"))
(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr011 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr011 simple-dispatch"))

(defmethod print-method       tr100 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr100 print-method"))
;;(defmethod print-dup          tr100 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr100 print-dup"))
;;(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr100 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr100 simple-dispatch"))

(defmethod print-method       tr101 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr101 print-method"))
;;(defmethod print-dup          tr101 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr101 print-dup"))
(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr101 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr101 simple-dispatch"))

(defmethod print-method       tr110 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr110 print-method"))
(defmethod print-dup          tr110 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr110 print-dup"))
;;(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr110 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr110 simple-dispatch"))

(defmethod print-method       tr111 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr111 print-method"))
(defmethod print-dup          tr111 [obj writer]  (.write writer "tr111 print-dup"))
(defmethod pp/simple-dispatch tr111 [obj]         (.write *out* "tr111 simple-dispatch"))


(def t000 (->tr000 10))
(def t001 (->tr001 20))
(def t010 (->tr010 30))
(def t011 (->tr011 40))
(def t100 (->tr100 50))
(def t101 (->tr101 60))
(def t110 (->tr110 70))
(def t111 (->tr111 80))
(def recs [t000 t001 t010 t011 t100 t101 t110 t111])


(def dt (java.time.LocalTime/now))
(defmethod print-dup java.time.LocalTime [obj writer] (.write writer "datetime_dup"))

(println "(pr ...) outputs the following")
(doseq [rec recs]
  (doseq [prppd [nil #(.write *out* "pprint-dispatch with" %)]]
    (binding [pp/*print-pprint-dispatch*
              (if prppd #(.write *out* (str "pprint-dipatch-with" %))
                  pp/*print-pprint-dispatch*)]
      (doseq [pd [false true]]
        (binding [*print-dup* pd]
          (let [ppdstr (format "%6s" (boolean pp/*print-pprint-dispatch*))
                dupstr (format "%6s" *print-dup*)
                outstr (pr-str rec)]
            (binding [*print-dup* false]
              (println ppdstr dupstr ":" outstr))))))))

(println "\n(pprint ...) outputs the following")
(doseq [rec recs]
  (doseq [prppd [false true]]
    (binding [pp/*print-pprint-dispatch*
              (if prppd #(.write *out* (str "pprint-dipatch-with" %))
                  pp/*print-pprint-dispatch*)]
      (doseq [pd [false true]]
        (binding [*print-dup* pd]
          (let [outstr
                (with-out-str
                  (pp/pprint {:ppdstr prppd
                              :dupstr pd
                              :dt dt
                              :strobj rec}))]
            (binding [*print-dup* false]
              (println outstr "\n"))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not ideal, but I haven't found better than [`pr`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pr) and [`pr-str`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pr-str).

Example REPL session :

```
  (ns my-ns)

  (defprotocol Foo
    (bazfn [this]))

  (defrecord Bar [a]
    Foo
    (bazfn [this] 123))


  (pr-str (Bar. "ok")) ;;=> "#my_ns.Bar{:a \"ok\"}"
  (pr (Bar. "ok"))     ;; prints the same as above
```